# Unable to Find Option for Exporting Custom ML Model for Object Detection in Google Vision (GCP Vertex AI)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision, machine-learning-model

I am working on a project where I have trained a custom machine learning model for object detection using Google Vision. However, I am unable to locate the option for exporting the trained model within the Google Vision dashboard to another Google Cloud **account** (not just a project). This step is crucial for integrating the model into a different project environment. I have thoroughly explored the dashboard but couldn't find any relevant option or documentation. The closest information I found was in the Vertex AI documentation, specifically related to [exporting edge models for object detection](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/export/export-edge-model#object-detection).

I tried following the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/export/export-edge-model#object-detection), and selected the Deploy & Test tab to view the available export formats. However, there were no available export formats at all! I also conducted searches on online forums and community discussions for similar issues, with no success in finding relevant information.

Would love any help or resources, documentation or steps that explicitly state how to export my vision AI model to another Google Cloud account! Thanks!!